# Labeling system in UHV, cryogenics

Tags: vacuum, cryogenics

So I am currently working with a cryo - fridge with a lot of cables in there. So the goal would be to get some labeling on the cables. An issue with just putting some plastic pieces with numbers in there or some label with ink is that it will break in the cryogenic environment or resp. start outgasing.
Teflon tape was suggested to use, but I am still unsure how we would do that. So does anyone have experience with this?

Thank you very much in Advance.

Comment: For what it's worth, dried sharpie writing tends to be UHV compatible.

Answer (score 0):

This should be migrated to Engineering SE. And I would use metal tags. There are machines that emboss them with text. You would want to precision clean the tags to remove any residual oils or chemicals that could off-gas